# Help with wmp.dll (Windows media player) to vb 6

Tags: vb6, windows-media-player, wmp, wmplib

I have a serious problem with my VB 6 application. In it, I have a reference to `wmp.dll` in a Form, the idea it's play media video files, i have a ListView called `LV1` in which I show the playlist filenames. I wish to know the current index from the current Playlist.

This sub is in charge of detecting the changes:

```
Private Sub Wmp1_CurrentItemChange(ByVal pdispMedia As Object)
```

I can get the totall count into the playlist with this line:

```
Val=Wmp1.currentPlaylist.Count
```

How I can obtain the current track (index) in reproduction, if i want coordinate this with my ListView, to select the same track with the same index into the playlist.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: **Did this previously work for you?** The way you say it's a "serious" problem makes me think that it's now broken. Or are you instead asking "is this possible?"

Comment: Mr cody when i said "serious" it's like "This problem Drives me Crazy". when you haves a source code without solve this round and round to you all the day.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setItemInfo` on the media before adding to `currentPlaylist` like this:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim sFile       As String
    Dim oMedia      As IWMPMedia

    sFile = Dir("c:\temp\*.avi")
    Do While LenB(sFile) <> 0
        Set oMedia = Wmp1.newMedia("c:\temp\" & sFile)
        oMedia.setItemInfo "Index", Wmp1.currentPlaylist.Count
        Wmp1.currentPlaylist.appendItem oMedia
        sFile = Dir
    Loop
End Sub

Private Sub Wmp1_CurrentItemChange(ByVal pdispMedia As Object)
    Debug.Print Wmp1.currentPlaylist.Item(Wmp1.currentMedia.getItemInfo("Index")).Name
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer. You have to search again in the loop

```
Dim i As Integer

For i = 0 To WindowsMediaPlayer1.currentPlaylist.Count - 1
If WindowsMediaPlayer1.currentPlaylist.Item(i).isIdentical(WindowsMediaPlayer1.currentMedia) = True Then Exit For
Next

List1.Selected(i) = True
```